# How to extract tags from strings

Tags: php, mysql, string, tags, extract

I'm using PHP, PDO extension and MySQL as default DBMS. also I have a prepared tags table with two `id` and `tag` columns in my database.

my purpose is **"auto extract matched tags from a string that exist in the tags table"** and my problem is making a PDO query to perform that.

for example if the string is "An Expensive And High Quality Computer hardware" , after removing words with less than 3 characters, if I execute a query like: `SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE %Expensive%And%High%Quality%Computer%;` , literal tags like "expensive" or "computer" will never found!

also executing a query like `SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag='expensive' OR tag='and' OR tag='high' OR tag='quality' OR tag='computer' OR tag='hardware';` will not contain tags like "High Quality" or "Expensive hardware".

this query will be executed once per each string and processing time will not matter in this case.

thank you in advance and sorry for my bad explain.

Comment: That's not how `%` works and chaining `OR` together is quite painful on large datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it; just put wildcards around each term:

```
SELECT id 
FROM tags 
WHERE tag='%expensive%' 
    OR tag='%high%' 
    OR tag='%quality%' 
    OR tag='%computer%'
    OR tag='%hardware%';
```

Note that I excluded "and" from the terms. You probably want to check the string length and don't use anything 3 chars or less, since "%and%" will match lots of things like "sandy" "bland" "grandiose" etc.

Comment: Thanx @digital-chris but still there is another little problem. this result will contain tags like "expensive tools" and this is not what I really expected!

Comment: I would suggest that "expensive tools" and "expensive computers" are bad tags, and just tag things "tools" and "computers"

Comment: yes, I'm agree with you but these tags collected by my costumer and i haven't time to filter them. is there any way to limit this result in order to choose multi-literal tags that contain only given words

Comment: You're asking for two things at once: exclusionary ("expensive computers" but not "expensive tools") AND inclusionary ("high quality hardware" and "expensive computers")... you can't do both at the same time. You might have to have multiple passes, for example first search for top level categories, then tags under that category.

Comment: so is this good idea to get similar tags from DB with your suggested query and then explode each result to single word with PHP and manipulate them to ensure contain only given words?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use something like:

```
SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE '%expensive%' OR tag LIKE '%and%' OR tag LIKE '%high%' OR tag LIKE '%quality%' OR tag LIKE '%computer%' OR tag LIKE '%hardware%';
```

In your query you're limiting your search to exact words like tag='hardware'. this will not match expensive hardware.